# sending request with token not work in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, token, access-token

I use web model-view-controller ( i use it at two project) and I'm trying to send this request to `UpdatePasswordFirstTime` but I have a problem with the authentication and it directs me to log in. I tried to go to data with the same token from Postman it still just directs me to login page.

Note: I use Identity Server in response function `UpdatePasswordFirstTime`

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdatePasswordFirstTime1(UserPasswordChangeResourcesFirstTime resources)
               
     var valtoken = claim.GetAccessToken().Result;
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", claim.GetAccessToken().Result);
    
                var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(JsonAppSettings.GetIdentityServerUrl() + "Users/UpdatePasswordFirstTime", new { Id =resources.Id, Password =resources.Password, ConfirmPassword =resources.ConfirmPassword});
    
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return new SignOutResult(new[] { CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme });
                }
                
                return new SignOutResult(new[] { CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme });
    
            }


// the response function 
another mvc
 



     [Authorize]
          [HttpPost]
          [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            

public async Task<ActionResult> UpdatePasswordFirstTime([FromBody] UserPasswordChangeResourcesFirstTime resources)
{
            {
    
                try
                {
                    //do something
                }
               
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //do something
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You're returning the same thing whether the request was successful or not!

Comment: @marc_s  i edit it

Comment: @phuzi yes it just for now but it's not give data so that